# Log of all mails that were send from server

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Recently we send Emails via cron job (using PHP's `mail()` function ) Unfortunately we didn't save the list of addresses on the database and we need to get the list.

Is there any log file on Ubuntu 12.04 server that save this kind of list?

Comment: I already check /var/log/mail.log but it is empty

Answer (score 2):

Check the mail server log (normally /var/log/maillog, but it depends on how you configure the email platform).

Comment: I check it but it's empty .